# re.sub replacing more text than wanted

Tags: regex, string

My text looks something like this:

```
blah blah [text in brackets] asda asdasd [more text in brackets 1234] blah
```

and I want to replace all text between brackets with "BRACKET"

```
blah blah BRACKET asda asdasd BRACKET blah
```

my regex is this:

```
re.sub('\[.*\]','BRAKCET',text)
```

which is producing

```
blah blah BRACKET blah
```

whenever there is another `]` in the string.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are greedy matching the regex

i.e [.*] tries to match the **LONGEST** string possible between '[' and ']'.
You need to use a Non-greedy regex by adding a '**?**'

```
>>> text = '''blah blah [text in brackets] asda asdasd [more text in brackets 1234] blah'''
>>> re.sub('\[.*?\]','BRAKCET',text)
'blah blah BRAKCET asda asdasd BRAKCET blah'
```

Look at '**Laziness instead of Greediness**' in the following link for more info

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-greedy option: `?`

Eg:

```
re.sub('[.*?]','BRAKCET',text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use none greedy token :

```
>>> s='blah blah [text in brackets] asda asdasd [more text in brackets 1234] blah'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\[.*?\]','BRAKCET',s)
'blah blah BRAKCET asda asdasd BRAKCET blah'
```

Comment: He is escaping the brackets. It just didn't show up because he used the wrong markup in the question.